# Parse push REST API error 400 "Bad Request"

Tags: ios, rest, push-notification, xamarin, parse-platform

I am developing an app for iOS using Xamarin iOS & MonoGame. I want to use Parse's push notifications through their REST API, so first I must create an installation object:

```
var bundle = new Dictionary<string, object>();
bundle.Add("channels", "");
bundle.Add("deviceType", "ios");
bundle.Add("deviceToken", _deviceToken);

string urlpath = "https://api.parse.com/1/installations";
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlpath);
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("X-Parse-Application-Id", _parseAppID);
httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("X-Parse-REST-API-KEY", _parseRestAPIKey);
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
string bundleString = bundle.ToJson();
byte[] buffer = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8").GetBytes(bundleString);
string result = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);
StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream());
requestWriter.Write(result, 0, result.Length);
requestWriter.Close();
WebResponse httpResponse = await httpWebRequest.GetResponseAsync();

Stream stream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream();
string json = string.Empty;

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        json += reader.ReadLine();
    }
}

JsonObject jsonObject = JsonObject.Parse(json);
_varStorage.Save("ObjectId", jsonObject.Get<string>("objectId"));
```

The bundleString value is:

> "{\"channels\":\"\",\"deviceType\":\"ios\",\"deviceToken\":\"46becd0a165be042eeab5a1ec96b8858065cbea7311479da16c0fd1c9428e2eb\"}"

This code raises a System.Net.WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError error 400 "Bad Request", and I can't see why.

Comment: Why aren't you using the Parse SDK to do this?  https://parse.com/products/xamarin

Comment: @Jason I am! but the Parse SDK for Xamarin iOS doesn't not have Parse push functionality implemented, therefore I am forced to do it through REST API. While I can go ahead and create a binding from the iOS SDK, this complicates a lot of the other code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more trail and error, I found that replacing this

```
byte[] buffer = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8").GetBytes(bundleString);

string result = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);

StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream());

requestWriter.Write(result, 0, result.Length);

requestWriter.Flush();

requestWriter.Close();
```

with this

```
httpWebRequest.ContentLength = bundleString.Length;

StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream());

requestWriter.Write(bundleString);

requestWriter.Flush();

requestWriter.Close();
```

fixed the problem, I don't know exactly why though.

Answer (score 1):

Channels is supposed to be an array of strings according to the documentation, https://www.parse.com/docs/rest#installations

```
bundle.Add("channels", new [] { "" });
```

Comment: unfortunately I am still getting the same exception.

Comment: Is there any additional information in the response beyond the error? Typically a `400 Bad Request` would be used to indicate a validation failure in the request data.

Comment: I couldnt find a way to copy everything in the exception into clipboard, but this is basically it --> "e = {System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckFinalStatus (System.Net.WebAsyncResult result) [0x0033b] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:..."

Comment: I was actually thinking in the content of the response, not in the exception.  Have you tried replicating the request with Fiddler or something similar?

Comment: the content is '"code":107,"error":"invalid json'. I have not used any tools like fiddler so far. I think there is something wrong with my bundle string, though I cant see it still.

Comment: Maybe try encoding with Newtonsoft.Json, https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/?

Comment: Just tried but nothing changed. I inspected the bundle string as JSON in both frameworks and they are identical.

Comment: Is it possible that your device token isn't valid?

Comment: when I receive the token in 'RegisteredForRemoteNotifications' method, I process it by removing brackets and spaces 'deviceToken.ToString().Trim('<', '>').Replace(" ", "")' then I use it. I am not sure parse requires this but I do it anyhow. I tried keeping the brackets and spaces, and I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

should you not be calling flush before closing your stream ?

```
requestWriter.Write(result, 0, result.Length);
requestWriter.Close();
```

Comment: Added it but still getting the exception. I am trying to somehow access the content of the response from the exception response field in the locals panel, but so far no success.

Comment: I was able to extract the content of the response '"code":107,"error":"invalid json'

Comment: Why no just use DataContractJsonSerializer - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Because ServiceStack seems to be doing the job just fine and I am using it also elsewhere in the project.